# Java - Why custom 404 error page is being executed even though a valid resourse is called?

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, http-status-code-404

In our java dynamic web project, we have 404 custom page registered in web.xml like this,

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/404Error.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

AFAIK, 404 error page gets executed when user requests for an unavailable resource, e.g., If user accidentally types "abc.jsp"(which is not available in our project) instead of typing "Abc.jsp" and then custom error message is shown.

I've observed that our 404Error.jsp is getting executed when any valid resource is called.
the code I have in 404Error.jsp is,

```
<% System.out.println("In 404 Error page !!")%>
```

I mean, we have "homePage.jsp" in our project, when I(user) call "homePage.jsp" the output of home page is displayed to me but I can see "In 404 Error page !!" sysout in my eclipse console.

Why 404Error.jsp java code is being executed even a valid resource is called?

Comment: it seems your code is fine . try to deploy your project and run it and check your web.xml file.

Comment: @ Sumn2u everything is working fine but when I try to execute homePage.jsp, home page content is getting displayed in the browser which is fine but I want to know why java code of 404Error.jsp is getting executed. I can see "In 404 Error page !!" line in my eclipse console.

Comment: scan your homepage.jsp  carefully it must be referring to some resource which is not available.

Comment: @ faisalbhagat you're right, a css file is referring to a jpeg file which is not available. I found the 404 error in browser debugger tools.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might be worth activating some kind of access-log or also print `request.getRequestURL()` to see what request is causing the 404 - my guess is that it's the browser requesting a favicon.ico that isn't there.